# The internal and external radius of a hemisphere are r and R respectively.Find the total surface area of the solid.

Tags: volume, solid-geometry

The internal and external radius of a hemisphere are r and R respectively.Find the total surface area of the solid.
Now this all seems to be very easy as
CSA of this hemisphere=2*pi*r^2+2*pi*R^2
what i cannot find out is the reaming area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: The "flat" part lies in a plane, and consists of a disk of radius $R$ with a disk of radius $r$ removed from its center. What's the area of the resulting annular region?

Comment: u see then its 2*pi*(R-r)^2=the area of the resulting annular region